# Create database error MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, command

I have the following error when trying to import .sql file into MYSQL from the command prompt.

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE\utilities>mysqldbimport --server=
root:password@localhost   <filepath>
# Source on localhost: ... connected.
# Importing definitions from <filepath>

ERROR: Invalid statement:
CREATE DATABASE `None`;
```

I have had a look at the command line parameters when using `mysqldbimport.exe` and found a `skip` command which gets past this error by adding `--skip CREATE_DB`, which imports however there is no data available as the process has been skipped.

How can I get around this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you manually create the database (either through console or other application), then skip the creation like you did there?

Edit;

Logging into MySQL console,

```
mysql> create database `testdb`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> use testdb;
Database changed
mysql>
```

You may have to edit the .sql file if possible, changing the Create database statement to "use testdb;", but it's hard to tell without knowing the full file.

Comment: that had sprung to mind, however I was not entirely sure how to do this, could you advise?